# How to setup Ant script to copy files from mac to windows?

Tags: windows, macos, ant, continuous-integration, jenkins

I am trying to setup Continuous integration for my IOS project. Jenkins is running on windows. Goes off calling ant script on mac. Once the builds run on mac I need the reports to be copied back to windows Jenkins reports folder. I couldn't do it using ant scp task from windows because it just allows us to put files from windows to mac but not the other way. Are there any other light weight alternatives?

Thanks,
Lalith

Comment: Does SCP really just allow to put files from Windows to mac? Actually Ant uses jsch to make the SSH related tasks run. However, the target machine needs to have an SSH server running. So you can try to install an SSH server software on the Windows machine. It may be the same as the FTP solution. (However I personally prefer SCP if you just want to transfer some files)

Comment: Yes I too prefer SCP but unfortunately I don't want to install openssh and Cygwin and all problems that come from that.. Looks like FTP can solve my issue.. I am almost done setting it up.

Comment: Happy to see that. However, on Windows I think WinSSHD from bitvise can be a choice (the difference is, it's only free for personal use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup an FTP server on your windows box and then use the ant [FTP Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html) to transfer the file.

Comment: Thanks this did it.. ftp task of ant doesn't throw any error.. I don't know why the SCP task is so screwed up.